# How to triangulate MATLAB mesh when delaunay failed

Tags: matlab-figure, triangulation

I need to perform a triangulation of matlab mesh format variables. Function surf do it perfectly somewhere internally, but delaunay failed. I think I just did not understand how mesh format works in MATLAB. To clarify below the example of code.

**Generate meshes with coordinates:**

```
close all
clear all
N=10;
R=5;
r=1;
u=linspace(0,2*pi,N);
v=linspace(0,2*pi,N);

[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);

x=(R+r.*cos(v))*cos(u);
y=(R+r.*cos(v))*sin(u);
z=r.*sin(v);
```

**Plot with surf()**

```
surf(x,y,z,'EdgeAlpha',0.1);
view([-52,64])

set(gca,'Color','none','Box','off')
axis off
```

[image]

**Plot after triangulation**

```
%% TRIANGULATION
TRI=delaunay(x,y,z);
trisurf(TRI,x,y,z,'EdgeAlpha',0.1)
view([-52,64])
set(gca,'Color','none','Box','off')
axis off
```

[image]

**Could You explain what is wrong and how should I obtain correct `TRI` variable?**

Comment: nothing is wrong. This is what delaunay triangulation is. It connects random points. How would the algorithm know which triangles to join and which not?

Comment: That is my problem. I could not understand algorithm under surf function. In my case surf works as should. So, I just need connect dots how `surf()` do. Just split each "rectangle" to 2 triangles.

Comment: In surf, you already know the neighbors of each point, as you have a meshgrid. U(i,j) is neighbor to 4, U(i±1,j±1). In a delaunay triangulation, this doesn't apply.  Because in your case, you (not the algorithm) know the neighbors, you could write some code that deletes triangles that are not created by neighbor nodes. This is not straightforward and you'll need a bit of thinking.

Comment: `U(i,j) is neighbor to 4, U(i±1,j±1)` THAT IS WHAT I NEED! Thank you!